# cannot get database data to the frontend

Tags: reactjs

[This is how the backend APi works for get API-... [postman [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARuUL.png) screenshot]..
I need to get database data from backend.this is my frontend (reactjs) code for the Get API method
AllUsers.js File

> ```
> import React, { useState, useEffect, forwardRef } from "react";
> import UserService from "../actions/User";
>
> export default function ViewUsers() {
>
>   const [userList, setUserList] = useState(null);
>
>
>      useEffect(() => {
>     handleUser()
>   }, [])
>
>   const handleUser =async () =>{
>
>     const users = await UserService.viewUser()
>     console.log(users, "gg")
>     setUserList(users);
>   }
>   console.log(userList,"1gmg")
> ```

UserService file

> 

```
 async viewUser() {
>     const data = await this.sendRequest({
>       method: 'GET',
>       url: `http://localhost:80/allusers`,
>       responseType: 'json',
>     });
>     return data.data;   }
```

Comment: What are you getting instead (*in the console.log*)?

Answer (score 0):

For fetching data from backend, `axios` is an easy and good choice. So install `axios`:

`$ npm i axios`

Import it:

`import axios from 'axios';`

Then use it:

```js
const handleUser =async ()=>{
  await axios.get('http://localhost:80/allusers')
  .then((response) => {
  setUserList(response.data);});
}
```

More information about axios: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-axios